# How do I get the ownership of a unregistered account/question in askubuntu?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I asked a question in here some hours ago. Unfortunately I did not register on my first visit. Now - as registered user (I created a new account on another computer) I'd like to comment on the solution (not working btw). How do I "overtake" the ownership of my own question?

edit: Thanks for moving - couldn't ask in meta without 5 points.

Comment: Your account can be merged. However you will need to link the question from the "un-registered" user.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6720/how-do-i-install-wmware-workstation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your accounts have been merged with the newer [account](https://askubuntu.com/users/3822) as the parent.